# How to reference the property of an object in an argument?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If an "Individual" class has properties like "health" and "mana", how could I write a function to do alter these properties by inputing the individual and the associated property as arguments?

For example, I know how to specific an individual by going:

```
 CastSpell(Individual ATTACKER, Individual TARGET, Spell SPELL)

ATTACKER.MANA = ATTACKER.MANA - SPELL.COST;
TARGET.HEALTH = TARGET.HEALTH - SPELL.DAMAGE;
```

but suppose I wanted, in the argument line, to specify not just an individual but an individuals property, for example so I could do the following:

```
ChangeStat(Individual TARGET, Individual.Property PROPERTYTOCHANGE, Float NewValue)

TARGET.PROPERTYTOCHANGE = NewValue;
```

Does that make sense? Like is there a way to, for lack of a better term, specify raw code in an argument line, to where I could do something to the effect of specifying the name of the property to change as a string, and then having it run "Target.(string) = NewValue"?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  You can pass in a string parameter identifying the property, and set that property using reflection, but that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Expressions.

```
public class Test
{
    public int Value {get;set;}
}

public void ChangeStat<T, TValue>(T target, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> memberLamda, TValue value)
{
    if (memberLamda.Body is MemberExpression memberExpr && memberExpr != null )
    {
        if (memberExpr.Member is PropertyInfo property && property != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(target, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
var test = new Test();
ChangeStat(test,x=>test.Value,2);
```

You can extend it further by using Extension Method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ChangeStat<T, TValue>(this T target, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> memberLamda, TValue value)
    {
        if (memberLamda.Body is MemberExpression memberExpr && memberExpr != null )
        {
            if (memberExpr.Member is PropertyInfo property && property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(target, value, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then.

```
var test = new Test();
test.ChangeStat(x=>test.Value,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't perfectly clear, when talking about raw code, you might be asking about lambda functions, but a better solution might be to use interfaces. I'll try to outline both.

The main question is 'where do you want the code to be'. If you want to create objects with properties that you specify at runtime you may do something like using a constructor/initializer (okay we can't have real constructors with unity but we can do things like):

```
 public void Init(System.Action<float> onMelee, System.Action<float> onMagic);
```

and in runtime do (on a newly instantiated object)

```
        TARGET.Init(
          (x)=>
           {
              if (x>1)
              Debug.Log("killd");
           },  // end of first argument
          (y)=>
           {
              TARGET.health+=y;
           }  // end of second argument
          );   

           CastSpell(Individual ATTACKER, Individual TARGET, Spell SPELL)
           {
              TARGET.onMagic(SPELL.strength*ATTACKER.strength);
           }
```

But this introduces a code smell, we are writing code that regards behaviour of objects in a slightly wrong place, as in there is this one class that keeps growing that contains all that code.

An elegant way to code this is to specify an interface which will make an Individual Attackable. We will introduce a dummy interface specification in the basse class but override it later for other objects (also, this way not only Individuals can be affected by attacks)

```
public Interface IAttackable
{
   void AttackMelee(float strength);
   void AttackMagic(float strength);
}
public class Individual: MonoBehaviour, IAttackable
{
  public virtual void AttackMelee(float x) { } // override
  public virtual void AttackMagic(float x) { } // override
}
```

This way you can compose an object by only specifying the way it responds to certain interface interactions, and the code lives within the specification of that object, and calling on that property.

```
public class MyMagicResistantCreature : Individual
{
  public override void AttackMelee(float x) { if (x>1) Debug.Log("died");}
  public override void AttackMagic(float x) { this.health+=x;}
}
```

The good thing is that now the code that describes an interaction doesn't have to know the specifics.

```
CastSpell(Individual ATTACKER, Individual TARGET, Spell SPELL)
{
    TARGET.AttackMagic(SPELL.strength*ATTACKER.strength);
}
```

Comment: The way I had all this in mind, and maybe I am thinking it out wrong, was to make individuals and spells objects, and then create a large "spell stack" function, that runs X number of times were X is the number of caster/target combinations. So if Bob casts an AOE that hits 3 people, it runs three times resolving for each caster/target combination.

Basically it was logically going to flow as this:

1. Attacker/target base stats pulled in
2. Apply any temporary modifiers to stats resulting from active abilities/potions
3. Call a spell "i.e. IceBlast(Attacker, Target)

Comment: I was going to do each ability as a function as well, since most will need to run their own algorithm based on the attacker and casters stats (With a hint of randomization as well) to determine the final damage/mana cost.

The spell stack would provide the spell function with the relevant stats (adjusted for any modifiers as a result of other abilities in play, potions, etc) and then pull back the raw damage and mana consumption resulting from the spell, and then the spell stack would change mana and health totals accordingly. 

I have never coded a game before

Comment: So I would do something like create IceBlast as a new spell (object), and then iceblast would have arguments of attacker and target and would output its final cost to the attacker and damage to the target, which is largely based on the properties of the attacker and target

For example, if the attackers strength is 80, the attack power of his physical abilities will be 80% effective. If this strength is 150, they will be 150% effective ,etc. So a spell that does 10 base damage, would deal 8 and 15 respectively, before accounting for the targets defenses.

Comment: there's many valid ways you can approach this. Making a spell an object on which you invoke a 'cast' method certainly makes sense. again - this is a question of where you want the code to live